# Permutation/Combination Assistance

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm stuck on the following permutation/combination problem...

John won 10 tickets to the Falcons/Ravens game by calling into a radio station’s contest. Find the number of ways he can invite family members if three of his cousins will only go with John if they can all go.

I think the answer should be C(6,4)=15. 4 because of john and 3 of his cousins, and 6 because 10-4=6. But this answer feels wrong. Can someone please help me out?

Thank You

Comment: How big is his family?

Comment: What are the conditions for wining a ticket to the Falcons/Ravens game? And how can some one win it?

Answer (score 3):

I will try to provide more of a walkthrough/hint than an actual answer (partially because Andre is correct that we need to know how many family members there are).

John has 10 tickets; presumably, he will need one himself. Therefore, he has to find a way to allocate the other 9 tickets. He could give 3 to his cousins, and then distribute the remaining 6 tickets among the remaining family members. Alternatively, he could give no tickets to these three cousins, and give all 9 tickets to the remaining family members.

Can you solve the problem now?